# How to order a MySQL query by last word of string with PHP PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a column in my database table called "name" and it stores the users names as "FirstName LastName". I want the query to return the members ordered alphabetically by their last names.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY name';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$members = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This doesn't work since the result is ordered by the whole name field and not the last name only. How could I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can FirstName have a space?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may order using `SUBSTRING_INDEX`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM members
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', -1);
```

By the way, it is generally bad table design to store the first and last name in the same column.  It would be much better to have two separate columns for the first and last names.

Comment: Yes, quite agree, the main issue here is the database design isn't very good. It's a nightmare to make this work - for example your solution wouldn't really work for "Carole Bayer Sager" as I'd expect her to be listed under "B". It'd work if she hyphenated it.

Comment: Is the rule then that you want to sort using the _second_ word in the name?

Comment: That would be down to the OP, really. I was just pointing out that some people have double surnames without a hyphen in them, and I think once you get outside the English naming system it gets more complex to overcome the flaw in the database design.